# Loading css files in index.html in between certain css files defined in angular cli-json

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli

I have some external stylesheets referring from another application in my index.html.

```
    <link href = "www.anotherapplication.com/css/anotherapp.css">
```

I have the application specific css in my angular-cli.json under "styles" like

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/foundation-sites/assets/foundation.scss",
    "my-application.scss"

  ],
```

Assuming that the base css for my application is the "anotherapp.css" that has to be included before "my-application.scss" but after "foundation.scss".

1) How do I order my css files in this case?

2) Also, Why is it that all the css/scss files defined in the angular-cli.json rendered as internal styles in the html page? (- making it difficult to view source in the chrome developer tools)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you always want to get the current `anotherapp.css`, otherwise you could of just save the file in the folder like `app/legacy/css` and modify `styles` config accordingly. So to always get the current `anotherapp.css` you can do by using [npm package download-cli](https://github.com/kevva/download-cli) and modifying some `npm scripts` and `cli configs`. Here is the setps:

- `npm install -g download-cli`
- add new npm script to your `package.json`
  `download": "download --out ./src/app/legacy/css www.anotherapplication.com/css/anotherapp.css"`
- modify your `ng serve/build/etc` script like
  `"build": "npm run download && ng build",`
  `"serve": "npm run download && ng serve"`
- modify your `styles` config like:

  `"styles": [`
      `"../node_modules/foundation-sites/assets/foundation.scss",`
      `"app/legacy/css/anotherapp.css",`
      `"my-application.scss"`
    `],`

To test the `download` script separately just run `npm run download`

**Tip:**
For debugging purposes you can name your global style bundles like so:

```
"styles": [
    { "input": "../node_modules/foundation-sites/assets/foundation.scss", "output": "foundation" },
    { "input": "app/legacy/css/anotherapp.css", "output": "anotherapp" }
    { "input": "my-application.scss", "output": "application" }
  ],
```

So this way angular cli instead of just producing one single `styles.bundle.js` will produce separate bundles like `foundation.bundle.js`, `anotherapp.bundle.js` and `application.bundle.js`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. But my question is that - How would I order my css files where "foundation.scss" comes first, then "anotherapp.scss" as second and then "my-application.scss" as third where the first css file and third css file are defined inside  angular-cli.json and the second css comes from an external css file defined in the index.html?

Comment: @Gsm I think I came up with the solution for you, just check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton! So, I did all the steps that you have mentioned but just a quick question to confirm: U meant 'current' anotherapp.css - Does it mean that the anotherapp.css in my app/legacy/css will get updated automatically as and when there is the update in the external css file from the website? i.e., whenever i run ng serve?